# How do web apps login you automatically on revisit without exposing the stored cookies or local storage to XSS?

Tags: cookies, web-applications, local-storage, xss

There are a lot of web apps, Facebook, Google, Slack, Quora etc. that re-login you on each visit, however if they use a cookie or the browser's local storage for storing a token or login information, those could be hijacked by a third party script. How do the web apps achieve protection against this?

Answer (score 0):

A script to be able to access a cookie of a certain origin (eg: facebook.com) would have to have been downloaded from the same origin, this is the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and is enforced by browsers.

Now, as you mention, an exception to this scenario would be when an attacker would manage to inject a script in the target website (XSS) so that it would be executed by another user while accessing that site, in this case the malicious script would have access to those cookies, to protect against this kind of scenarios it was introduced the [HttpOnly flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly), designed to make selected cookies inaccessible to client side scripts.